# How can i deploy a php script with a python backend

Tags: python, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to aws and I want to deploy a php script to ec2 which executes a python file in the backend. I am using windows, how do i go about deploying this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to ssh into the EC2, place the scripts in the EC2 and execute them? What do you mean with 'deploying this'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already tested it using Linux server you can use

```
<?php 

$path = escapeshellcmd('backend.py');
$exec = shell_exec($command);
if($exec){
// verify what the python file returned as function
}
?>
```

Important : Make sure you gave the file using your root terminal the command

```
$ chmod 777 path_to_your_php
```